# Field testService in com.test.controller.TestController required a bean of type 'com.test.service.TestService' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockmvc

My application runs fine when I startup and am facing a weird issue when writing a unit test for controller. Looks very basic and simple but stuck here for a long time. I tried several variations including Mockito.Annotations, adding Qualifier with bean name as mentioned  in Baeldung but still get the basic error. Please assist in resolving this issue.

Controller Class:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Component
public class UserController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController .class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userService")
    private userService userService;
}
```

Service Interface:

```
public interface UserService {
    public User getUserById(Integer userId);
}
```

Service Implementation

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);
     @Autowired
    RecordService recordService;
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;
}
```

Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { UserController.class, UserService.class })
public class UserControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    UserController userController;

    @Mock
    UserService userService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // tried this to see if it helps
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(testController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testWelcome() throws Exception {
        // Mocking Controller
        testController = mock(TestController.class);
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()) .andExpect(view().name("Welcome to Test-Service."));
    }
}
```

My application runs fine when I startup and am facing a weird issue when writing a unit test for controller. Looks very basic and simple but stuck here for a long time. I tried several variations including Mockito.Annotations, adding Qualifier with bean name as mentioned  in Baeldung but still get the basic error. Please assist in resolving this issue.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************   
Field testService in com.test.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.service.UserService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=testService)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.service.UserService' in your configuration.
```

Comment: 1.`UserController` only needs `@Controller` annotation 2. Please remove the `(classes = { UserController.class, UserService.class })` and `@RunWith` from `UserControllerTest` 3. You may use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` for userService (not an issue here , but a suggestion )

Answer (score 0):

So you're loading a controller and wish to mock out the actual service that the controller turns to.
Such a test can be written for two reasons:

1. The controller has some code that should be checked at the level of "unit tests". For this you don't need spring at all - run the test with Mockito Runner, inject the Mock of the service into "controller-class-under-test" and check the code. The general recommendation/best practice is to keep minimal code in controller and do not create extensive code at this level.
2. You want to check that the controller is defined correctly (with all the mappings, annotations and everything). For this kind of tests, spring mvc already has a solution that you seem to be trying to re-invent: `@WebMvcTest`. It does the following:

   - Creates a "mini mvc" (Dispatching infra) in memory - something you can interact with with a special MockMVC class from the test, define expectations and "call" the request.
   - Runs a slice of your application with Controllers mapped in this mock engine
   - Automatically configured in a way that it won't load `@Service` / `@Repository` annotated classes - only rest controller (s).
   - The service will be mocked and expectations from it can be specified in the test.

There are many tutorials for Mock MVC testing, quick googling reveals [this one](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-boot-mockmvc-example/) for example

Comment: I am still getting the same error and going through the link in detail.

Comment: '@Mock' is used for unit tests (mockito, no spring + mockito runner). '@MockBean' is used for mocking out the spring beans

Comment: Thanks, it worked finally. had a weird config error but this is true that using this approach decoupled SpringBoot dependency and just used Mockito